# is there a way to make template but not render it in plates php

Tags: php, templates, model-view-controller, plates

Is there a way in [plates](http://platesphp.com/templates/data/) php where I can make a template in a controller but render it using another controller. Say I have two controllers. HeaderController and a SearchController.

**SearchController**

```
class Search extends \system\core\BaseController
{
    public function Index()
    {
        $data['text_search'] = 'Search..';

        // This $this->template->render down below is what I don't want now
        // okay asign the data but do not display the template yet
        echo $this->template->render('common/search', $data);
    }
}
```

The dummy SearchController should assign $data to the template search.tpl but not render/display the template.

This is where I will be calling the above controller

**HeaderController**

```
class HeaderController extends \system\core\BaseController
{
    public function Index()
    {
        // Some codes

        // Call / load the SearchController and asign it to $data['search'] 
        $data['search'] =  $this->load->controller('common/SearchController');

        // and then pass all $data and render/display it.
        echo $this->template->render('common/header', $data);
    }
}
```

Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue actually comes from the fact, that you are using `echo` within your class. If your "controllers" (well, they actually seem to be a combination of view and controller) were to `return` either the content or `Response` class instance, then you problem should disappear.

Comment: tereško, man .. that was dumb. Thank you buddy, the return helped.